# Why there is no invert tag selection for the filter setting?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I'm interested with many areas, but I can't thumb up all of them by tags.
Why can't I receive questions with all the tags, then after some days' usage, I can remove the hated ones in the filter.
I think it should be a basic functionality, if I'm wrong, please point out for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you look under Your profile > Preferences you will find a favorite tags and ignored tags sections. You can simply add your disliked tags to the ignored section and select the "hide ignored tags" check box.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it helps a little. But the ignored text is just faded and still occupy some space, is it possible to hide them completely?

Comment: @zbie I believe that's the best your going to get.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I can only accept this for now. Never mind that I just received thousands of questions without tag filter this morning....